# Writing to an Excel cell erases all other existing data in that particular row

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an existing Excel file, in which I need to update some cell data.

I am reading the xlsx file like this:

```
File file = Paths.get("location/template.xlsx").toFile();
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
```

Then I am updating the cell like this:

```
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
Row row = sheet.createRow(cellRowNum); //because sheet.getRow(cellRowNum) was returning null.
Cell cell = row.createCell(cellColumnNum);
cell.setCellValue(value);
```

So now, the value is correctly visible on the cell, but all other existing data in that row is erased/overwritten.

Please help me figure this out? I need to use Apache POI only.

Comment: You need to call `getRow` and then only `createRow` if it is null - you are creating a new row each time which wipes it

Comment: Instead of editing a comment in your question that your problem is now solved, either accept the answer that helped you solve it, or post your own answer and accept that after the timeout.

Comment: Oh okay. Doing.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation we have 3 methods. (https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html)

- `Cell createCell(int column)` Use this to create new cells within the row and return it.
- `Cell getCell(int cellnum)` Get the cell representing a given column (logical cell) 0-based. If you ask for a cell that is not defined....you get a null.
- `Cell getCell(int cellnum, Row.MissingCellPolicy policy)` Returns the cell at the given (0 based) index, with the specified Row.MissingCellPolicy

The last one combines the best of both.

Answer (score 0):

Correct Answer -> I wasn't aware that POI will return null on empty rows, but will return the row when there is some value. It looks obvious, but there are some many workbooks (SXSSF, XSSF, HSSF etc), that I got confused. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: All the different POI SpreadSheet interfaces (HSSF, XSSF etc) do exactly the same thing with undefined rows/cells!